# Spring Configuration xml file with two beans of the same type NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

I am trying to set up a test applicationContext file for running integration tests on a project that I am working on. 
I have two classes that have fields that are marked as @Resource. One class I can change and one I cannot as it is imported from a different project that I don't have any permissions to change. I cannot get my configuration file to set these @Resouces fields without giving me an org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.

Simple example:
appconfig.xml file

```
...Typical spring setup...
<bean id="baseUrl" class="java.lang.String">
<constructor-arg value="myURL"/>
</bean>
<bean id="supportedLang" class = "java.lang.String">
<constructor-arg value="en"/>
</bean>
```

Class that uses baseURL, (I have control to change, simplified Version)

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyService implements AnotherService{
@Resource
private String baseUrl;
public String getBaseUrl(){return baseUrl;}
public void setBaseURL(String baseURL){this.baseUrl = baseUrl;}

}
```

Class that uses supportedLang (I don't have access to change this class simplified version)

```
@Service
public class LangSupportImpl implements InitializaingBean, LangSupport{
@Resource(name= "supportedLang")
private String twoLetterSupportedLang;
public getTwoLetterSupportedLang(){return this.twoLetterSupportedLang;}
}
```

If I don't set up the beans in the application config file I get a no bean defined error instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which bean causes exception?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'iCalService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: baseUrl,supportedLang

this is the specific error I get it is thrown when trying to create the MyService class. If I take out the Bean for supportedLang, I get an error stating that that bean is not defined but MyService seems to be created correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `@Resource(name = "baseUrl")` in your `MyService` class. This will tell Spring which exact bean to take and will resolve ambiguity.

Another option is to change XML configuration and add `primary="true"` to declaration of `baseUrl` bean

Comment: I tried the @Resource name value, It didn't work. but setting primary to true did. thanks,